# Linest function in vba cannot obtain coefficients for 4th order polynomial

Tags: vba, excel

I am having issues with applying the function linest to my code, in order to obtain the best fit polynomials. The issue here is that my code works perfectly when obtaining a 2nd order polynomial regression, but any higher order attempts fail. This is my code:

```
Dim x_val As Range
Dim y_val As Range
Set x_val = Range(Cells(8, 19), Cells(7 + temperatures.count, 19))
Set y_val = Range(Cells(8, 20), Cells(7 + temperatures.count, 20))

Coefficients = Application.LinEst(y_val, Application.Power(x_val, Array(1, 2, 3, 4)))

.Cells(7, 23) = Coefficients(1) 'This is the line where i get the error "type mismatch"
.Cells(8, 23) = Coefficients(2)
.Cells(9, 23) = Coefficients(3)
.Cells(10, 23) = Coefficients(4)
.Cells(11, 23) = Coefficients(5)
```

Note that the program works when i use the following excel formula, but i need to be able to select ranges of variable size to determine the fitting coefficients, so its not an option

```
Coefficients = Application.Evaluate("=linest(T8:T74,S8:S74^{1,2,3,4})")
```

Comment: You can still select your ranges of any size and build up the formula that goes inside the `Evaluate` function. Something like `Dim rng As Range; Set rng = Range("T8:T33"); ...Evaluate("=linest(" & rng.Address & ",S8:S33^{1,2,3,4})")` will work just fine (plus any combination you can come up with.

Comment: Did PeterT's comment solve this?

Comment: One possibility for the error is that the defined ranges are not the same size.  Although, from your post, it doesn't appear to be the case.  Another possibility might be that one or more cells contain an error value, such as #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #N/A, etc.  But since you don't get an error with your formula, it also doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: @Qharr It didn't, it still gives me the same error. I'm confused as to why. I even checked the Strings of the range addresses and they're the same as the ones i used to get the correct coefficients

Comment: There's something else going on.  That formula works perfectly OK on sample data here:  `Coefficients = Application.LinEst(y, Application.Power(x, Array(1, 2, 3, 4)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it through trial and error. All I had to do is add .WorksheetFunction to my code such as this.

```
Coefficients = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(y_val, Application.Power(x_val, Array(1, 2, 3, 4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this pattern but make sure you are working in the right sheet so add the sheet reference in. This worked for me.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()
    Dim x As Range, y As Range
    Set x = Range("T8:T74")
    Set y = Range("S8:S74")

    Dim b As Double, C1 As Double, C2 As Double, C3 As Double, C4 As Double
    b = Evaluate("INDEX(LINEST(" & x.Address & "," & y.Address & "^{1,2,3,4}),1,5)")
    C1 = Evaluate("INDEX(LINEST(" & x.Address & "," & y.Address & "^{1,2,3,4}),1,4)")
    C2 = Evaluate("INDEX(LINEST(" & x.Address & "," & y.Address & "^{1,2,3,4}),1,3)")
    C3 = Evaluate("INDEX(LINEST(" & x.Address & "," & y.Address & "^{1,2,3,4}),1,2)")
    C4 = Evaluate("INDEX(LINEST(" & x.Address & "," & y.Address & "^{1,2,3,4}),1)")

    Debug.Print b, C1, C2, C3, C4
End Sub
```

**Test run:**

[image: Test run]

Comment: This still doesn't allow me to use variable indexes like x_val.Address

Comment: Example added showing does work with range and range.address from variables.