# How can I use LINEST for polynomial function inside VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am basically trying to get the following code work:

```
Public Function Qcapability(GenXcoords As Range, GenYcoords As Range)

    answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst( _
         Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(GenYcoords), _
         Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(GenXcoords)^{1,2})

    Qcapability = answer
End Function
```

I typed the LINEST function as I would use it inside a cell. I do not know how to implement the `"^{1,2}"` in VBA format. How do I do this?

Comment: You might find it easier to use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method here, so you can use the regular formula syntax (though as a string) in your VBA.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657577/linest-function-in-vba-cannot-obtain-coefficients-for-4th-order-polynomial/51659029#51659029   Please see accepted answer from that. If works can close this as duplicate.